# Programmatically creating a connection string for mapping an Entity Framework Code-First model with an existing Sql Server Compact database

Tags: entity-framework, compact-framework, connection-string, code-first

I've successfully mapped an Entity Framework Code-First data model with an existing Sql Server Compact database by a declarative approach using `app.config` but it would be great if I could build such connection *programmatically* with perhaps the help of the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` (System.Data.EntityClient) class. Unfortunately this approach is not working as the `[DbContext].Connection.ConnectionString` is not accepting most of its properties.

Here's the actual working code with the faulty one commented out:

**Book.cs**

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Catalog.cs**

```
public class Catalog : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="Catalog"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0"
      connectionString="Data Source=res/Catalog.sdf"
  />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Main()**

```
static void Main()
{
    // var res = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "res");
    // var str = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    // str.Name = "Catalog";
    // str.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";
    // str.ProviderConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source {0}", Path.Combine(res, "Catalog.sdf"));

    try
    {
        using (var catalog = new Catalog())
        {
            // catalog.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = str.ConnectionString;

    // remaining code not relevant - skipped
```

I've tried using other builder classes such as `SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder` (System.Data.SqlServerCe), `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` (System.Data.SqlClient) and even `DbConnectionStringBuilder` (System.Data.Common) but apparently none of them seem to match what `[DbContext].Connection.ConnectionString` is expecting.

Should I conclude there is no programmatic way to achieve this?
Any advice will be surely appreciated. Thanks much in advance for your contributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server Compact 4.0 and `DbContext` with code first you cannot use `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` - it builds connection string for EF with EDMX file. You need `SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder` from `System.Data.SqlServerCe` assembly with version 4.0.0.0!

You should also pass the connection string to the context instance through the constructor - `DbContext` has constructor accepting name of the connection string (from configuration) or connection string itself.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Ladislav. I've tried creating the connection string with `SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder` but it results in an exception: `The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string`. Would you mind providing us with a sample code snippet that compiles?

Answer (score 2):

Open a DbConnection and pass it to the DbContext constructor or use a DefaultConnectionFactory:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory
    = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

using (var catalog = new Catalog("Catalog.sdf"))
{
}
```

SqlCeConnectionFactory is a ready-to-use connection factory provided by Microsoft, but you can also implement your own factory.