# Hiding App.config in Resources

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, app-config

I've searched around for a while but I just can't find a specific answer for this.

In my current C# project I have an App.config file I need in order for my EDM context to find the database connection.

I have the need for my application to consist of a single .exe file, but because of the  App.config it will generate the .exe.config next to my .exe file and requires it in order to run correctly.

Is there a way to add the connection string for my DB context programmatically or is it possible to store the App.config in the resources?

How can I pass the connection string to my database context?

Comment: What kind of "EDM context" do you use to access the DB? If you tell us we may can tell you how to configure it without the App.config...

Comment: It's automatically generated by the Models.edmx I'm using, I added a ADO.NET Entity Data Model. It's a `public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext` having a few `ObjectSet<ModelClass>` fields

Comment: That's pointless.  You store the setting in app.exe.config so that it is easy to edit and allows your program to work on another machine with a different dbase server.  Storing it in a resource prevents it from being edited.  You might just as well hard-code it in your source code.

Comment: I would hardcode it if I could, see comment 1 & 2 + updated question

Comment: Can You pass it in command line arguments

Comment: That would mean I would still need another file (the config file), the target is that I can use my app stand-alone, just the .exe, no other files needed

Comment: Yes, you can still hardcode the connection string. One of the parameters to your entity constructor accepts a connection string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the last comment of Amen Ayach pointed me to the correct solution

instead of instancing my ObjectContext without parameters, I just had to pass the connection string from my App.config and I was able to remove the App.config

Instead of

```
Entities = new MyEntities();
```

i called

```
Entities = new MyEntities( "metadata=res://*/Models.csdl|res://*/Models.ssdl|res://*/Models.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=sql-server;initial catalog=initialDatabase;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework\"" );
```

Visual Studio automatically overloads the constructor of your context class it creates allowing you to pass a connection string manually

Answer (score -2):

You can save and read setting like all advanced programs in **Registry**, and forget app.config, and that is how to do it:

```
public object GetRegistryValue(string KeyName, object DefaultValue)
        {
            object res = null;
            try
            {
                Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer c = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer();
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey k = c.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\YourAppName", true);
                if (k != null)
                {
                    res = k.GetValue(KeyName, DefaultValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    k = c.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\YourAppName");
                }
                if (k != null)
                    k.Close();
                // ex As Exception
            }
            catch
            {
                //PromptMsg(ex)
            }
            return res;
        }

public void SetRegistryValue(string KeyName, object _Value)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer c = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer();

                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey k = c.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\YourAppName", true);
                if (k != null)
                {
                    k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    k = c.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\YourAppName");
                    k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value);
                }
                if (k != null)
                    k.Close();
                // ex As Exception
            }
            catch
            {
                //PromptMsg(ex)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, it's not about that I don't know how or where to store my config, more about that I don't want the App.config but don't know how to pass my connection string otherwise

Comment: That is my answer you can save connection in registry with SetRegistryValue and then read it with GetRegistryValue to load con to your data context

Comment: But how do I pass the connection string to the database context?
I read the connection string from somewhere, but what comes after that? How do I tell my context "here, connect to the server in this string"

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558318/programmatically-creating-a-connection-string-for-mapping-an-entity-framework-co